# Install and Deploy Django app on Heroku

Tags: django, git, postgresql, heroku

I often forget steps and wish there was a quick instructional guide on deploying a django project on Heroku.

**How to Install and Deploy a Django app on Heroku?**

I have posted a step-by-steps answer for steps that have worked for me.

## You will get:

- Django app both on heroku and your computer.
- Postgres databases on both machines
- git/bitbucket
- authentication: login, logout, register, forgot pass, email authentication only (optional & default)
- static files working on both machines
- Bootstrap 3.0.3 included
- South Migrations ([instructions](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/part1.html))

## Requirements

- heroku account
- github/bitbucket account
- mac with OSX (tested on 10.9)

Comment: I agree with @MilenA.Radev here, this is a step-by-step guide and would be more suitable on github.io or other such platform. Anyway,  it should be good resource for folks searching on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my other answer, the process is well described, but takes time. So I have made a ready installation that is good to go in less than 15minutes.

https://github.com/mgpepe/django-heroku-15

If you'd prefer the full explanation with the long path see the answer below.

Comment: Also have a look at the [official Heroku Django Template](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-django-template).

Answer (score 5):

## UPDATE:

To do an installation the quick way, check out the other answer.

---

## Folder structure

- PROJECT_WRAPPER - it will hold everything, including PS
- DJANGO_PROJECT - it will hold the code
- DJANGO_APP - the main app will have that name

Anywhere you see those, replace with your real names!!!

## Virtual Env

If you don’t have `virtualenv`, you need to get it. It will allow you to have separate installations of software for each project:

```
pip install virtualenv
```

then we create our project:

```
cd ~
mkdir PROJECT_WRAPPER && cd PROJECT_WRAPPER
virtualenv venv
```

now you have a dedicated folder that will contain independent installations and version of python, django, etc.

We activate and and start working on project the following way:

```
source venv/bin/activate
```

## Postrges app

Just before we continue, we will install postgres.app. Grab it from:
http://postgresapp.com/

Install.

We will now hook up our environment with it:

```
PATH=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/:$PATH
```

## Requirements.txt

Now we will need to install the following things:

- Python, Django - no explanations required
- South - Migrations of database (dev version of Django does not require it)
- django-toolbelt - required by heroku and includes everything required for heroku
- psycopg - postgres database
- simplejson, mixpanel - these are optional, you could skip if you didn't like

So to create the requirements.txt file, we will get it ready from my git repository:

```
clone https://raw2.github.com/mgpepe/django-heroku-15/master/requirements.txt -o requirements.txt
```

Now with one command we will install everything from our requirements.txt:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Great, now we can verify that we have django with:

```
python -c "import django; print(django.get_version())"
```

## Start a Django Project

Let’s start the project with this line and **don’t forget the dot in the end**:

```
django-admin.py startproject DJANGO_PROJECT .
```

Now if you type `ls` you should see a folder with your project name that contains your Django project.

To see if it all works run:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

## DATABASE

Run the Postgres app.

Create a database with (I used my osx username):

```
createdb YOUR_DATABASE_NAME --owner=YOUR_OSX_USERNAME
```

change the `DATABASES` to look like this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'YOUR_DATABASE_NAME',
        'USER': 'YOUR_OSX_USERNAME',
        'PASSWORD': 'YOUR_DATABASE_PASSWORD', #might be empty string ''
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        # 'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

And also let’s hook up the South migrations. Your `INSTALLED_APPS` should look like that:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'south',
)
```

Change the `SECRET_KEY` variable to something else than what it is.

Now if everything was fine you should be able to create the first tables with:

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

## FIRST APP

Now make your first app in your project

```
python manage.py startapp DJANGO_APP
```

in the file: `~/PROJECT_WRAPPER/DJANGO_PROJECT/settings.py`

add the `DJANGO_APP` app to the list in the variable `INSTALLED_APPS`. Should look like that:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'south',
    'DJANGO_APP',
)
```

## TEMPLATES

in settings file add the line:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
```

In order for the templates to be well organized and working, we will copy base.html in one folder and the rest of templates in the app itself:

```
cd ~/PROJECT_WRAPPER/
mkdir templates
curl https://raw2.github.com/mgpepe/django-heroku-15/master/templates/base.html -o base.html
```

Now the rest of templates:

```
cd ~/PROJECT_WRAPPER/DJANGO_APP/
mkdir templates && cd templates
mkdir DJANGO_APP
curl https://raw2.github.com/mgpepe/django-heroku-15/master/DjMainApp/templates/DjMainApp/changepass.html -o changepass.html
curl https://raw2.github.com/mgpepe/django-heroku-15/master/DjMainApp/templates/DjMainApp/forgot_pass.html -o forgot_pass.html
curl https://raw2.github.com/mgpepe/django-heroku-15/master/DjMainApp/templates/DjMainApp/home.html -o home.html
curl https://raw2.github.com/mgpepe/django-heroku-15/master/DjMainApp/templates/DjMainApp/login.html -o login.html
curl https://raw2.github.com/mgpepe/django-heroku-15/master/DjMainApp/templates/DjMainApp/logout.html -o logout.html
curl https://raw2.github.com/mgpepe/django-heroku-15/master/DjMainApp/templates/DjMainApp/registration.html -o registration.html
curl https://raw2.github.com/mgpepe/django-heroku-15/master/DjMainApp/templates/DjMainApp/splash.html -o splash.html
```

## AUTH SYSTEM WITH EMAIL

Since it has been lately fashionable to use email instead of username, we will do that too.

*NOTE: if you decide not to use it, you can skip this step BUT you have to edit the views and templates to use username instead of email. *

In settings add the following line:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (DJANGO_PROJECT.backends.EmailAuthBackend’,)
```

then copy the file backends.py in our project directory:

```
cd ~/PROJECT_WRAPPER/DJANGO_PROJECT/
clone https://raw2.github.com/mgpepe/django-heroku-15/master/DjangoHerokuIn15/backends.py -o backends.py
```

## HEROKU LOCALLY

You can simulate heroku working on your computer with Foreman. Let’s create the simplest configuration file:

```
cd ~/PROJECT_WRAPPER
echo "web: gunicorn DJANGO_PROJECT.wsgi" > Procfile
foreman start
```

Now that you see it working without errors stop it with `CTRL+C`

in settings all the way at the bottom add:

```
# HEROKU
###########################
# Parse database configuration from $DATABASE_URL
if os.environ.has_key('DATABASE_URL'):
    import dj_database_url
    DATABASES['default'] =  dj_database_url.config()

# Honor the 'X-Forwarded-Proto' header for request.is_secure()
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')

# Allow all host headers
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
```

In your `DJANGO_PROJECT/wsgi.py` file and add the following to bottom:

```
from dj_static import Cling
application = Cling(get_wsgi_application())
```

## STATIC FILES

Ideally you would server static files from Amazon or something like that. But for simple sites you could use Django. Setting it up requires you to append this in settings file:

```
# HEROKU STATIC ASSETS CONFIGURATION
################################
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

and put all static files in a specific folder. First go to your project folder with something like:

```
cd ~/PROJECT_WRAPPER/DJANGO_PROJECT/
```

and now you can just copy/paste the rest:

```
mkdir static && cd static
mkdir css && cd css
clone https://raw2.github.com/mgpepe/django-heroku-15/master/DjangoHerokuIn15/static/css/bootstrap.min.css -o bootstrap.min.css
clone https://raw2.github.com/mgpepe/django-heroku-15/master/DjangoHerokuIn15/static/css/styles.css -o styles.css
cd ..
mkdir js && cd js
clone https://raw2.github.com/mgpepe/django-heroku-15/master/DjangoHerokuIn15/static/js/bootstrap.min.js -o bootstrap.min.js
cd ..
mkdir img && cd img
```

In this last folder, you will put all images you need.

## URL SETTINGS AND VIEWS

In urls.py copy these lines right before ‘example’:

```
url(r'^$', "pmfmain.views.splash", name="splash"),
url(r'^login$', "pmfmain.views.login_view", name="login"),
url(r'^signup$', "pmfmain.views.register", name="signup"),
url(r'^forgot$', "pmfmain.views.forgot_pass", name="forgotmypass"),
url(r'^logout$', "pmfmain.views.logout_user", name="logout"),
url(r'^dashboard$', "pmfmain.views.home", name="home”),
```

then copy views.py from my github repo to your DJANGO_PROJECT folder:

```
cd ~/PROJECT_WRAPPER/DJANGO_APP/
rm views.py
clone https://raw2.github.com/mgpepe/django-heroku-15/master/DjMainApp/views.py -o views.py
```

Do a find & replace replacing `DjMainApp` with your real DJANGO_APP name throughout the whole `views.py`

clone https://raw2.github.com/mgpepe/django-heroku-15/master/DjMainApp/forms.py -o forms.py

## GIT

Some files need not be in git, so let’s set the config for this:

```
echo -e "venv\n*.pyc\n*.log\n*.pot\nstaticfiles" > .gitignore
```

and now lets commit:

```
git init
git add . 
git commit -m ‘initial commit of django app’
```

Create a repository in git, then copy the git url (the one that ends in .git). Then:

```
git remote add origin THE_URL
git pull origin master
```

## BITBUCKET ALTERNATIVE

If you don’t want to pay for github and you want your repository private, you can use bitbucket.

Login to your account
Create a new repository
Click add existing project

```
git remote add origin https://USERNAME@bitbucket.org/USERNAME/REPOSITORY_NAME.git
```

## MULTIPLE HEROKU ACCOUNTS & KEYS

Even if you never have to have multiple heroku accounts, it is an easy way to setup and use it even for one account. So on we go:

```
cd ~
heroku plugins:install git://github.com/ddollar/heroku-accounts.git
```

the add a heroku account with:

- `heroku accounts:add personal`
- Enter your Heroku credentials.
- Email:YOUR_HEROKU_EMAIL
- Password: YOUR_HEROKU_PASSWORD

It says it in the console, and you have to do it:

Add the following to your ~/.ssh/config

```
Host heroku.personal
  HostName heroku.com
  IdentityFile /PATH/TO/PRIVATE/KEY
  IdentitiesOnly yes
```

Go to your project folder with something like:

```
cd ~/PROJECT_WRAPPER
```

and then set the new account as:

```
heroku accounts:set personal
```

To create a new ssh KEY:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

When asked for name, write the full path and name as shown. then type your password or leave blank

Then add the keys both to your OSX and heroku:

```
heroku keys:add  ~/.ssh/YOUR_KEY_NAME.pub
ssh-add ~/.ssh/YOUR_KEY_NAME
```

## DEPLOYING HEROKU FILES

Now that you have keys in order, you should be able to do
heroku apps

and see that there are no apps. To add your first app:

```
heroku apps:create YOUR_APP_NAME
```

And now to upload to the server:

```
git push heroku master
```

now go to YOUR_APP_NAME.herokuapp.com to see your site!

## DOMAIN SETUP

remains to be explained if anybody wants, let me know

## NOTES

In-depth documentation at:

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial01/
- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-django

Answer (score 1):

> ***THESE ARE THE ERRORS WHICH I FIND WHILE WORKING ON DJANGO FOR 2 YEARS [ENJOY]***

> 1. Dyno should be added/seen in heroku->resources and if it is not added in resources of Heroku then it means there is a problem in the

> "Procfile"

```
web: gunicorn [django_project].wsgi --log-file -
```

> "django_project" above is your project name , change it to your project name

> 2. Remember to do changes in the settings.py file

DEBUG=True

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["your-app.herokuapp.com","127.0.0.1"]
```

> 3. add this in `settings.py` file
>
>    #->this should be in the middleware

```
'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
```

> ```
> #->this at the bottom
> ```

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

> 4. [ First do "pip install django-heroku" ]

> place this at the top of `settings.py` file:

```
import django_heroku
```

> ```
> place this at the bottom of "settings.py" file:
> ```

```
django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

> 5. Heroku only works with postgres, *remember this*

> [ go to https://www.elephantsql.com/ ]

```
  DATABASES = {
        "default": {
            "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql",
            "NAME": "",  
            "USER": "",
            "PASSWORD": "",
            "HOST": "",
            "PORT": "5432",
        }
    }
```

> Make Sure database in the background, if not running, start "postgres" in the services.msc.
> [ This is in taskmanager->Services->postgresql->right click->start]

```
python manage.py migrate
```

> 6. go to "your app" in heroku and go to "settings" and select "Add buildpack" in the settings and select "python"

> ####################### Important ##############################

> ==> Create a new Git repository Initialize a git repository in a new or
> existing directory

```
cd my-project/
git init
heroku git:remote -a iris-django-ml
```

> ==> Deploy your application
>
> Commit your code to the repository and deploy it to Heroku using Git.

```
git add .
git commit -am "make it better"
git push heroku master
```

> 7. "run this command in your directory"

```
heroku login
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

> 8. restart again with deleting your git file of your working directory, delete heroku project (settings -> bottom)